# Proving something is a basis?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $M$ be a free $R$-module and $\{e_i\}$, $i\in I$ a basis of $M$. Prove that given an isomorphism
>   $f : M \to N$ of $R$-modules, $\left\{f (e_i) \mid i \in I\right\}$ is a basis of $N$.

I know the definition of basis is that it has to be linearly independent and a generator, but I cant see what I am supposed to be doing that?

Please instead of proving can you please just guide me.

Many thanks

Comment: use LaTeX and the fact that $f$ is injective, i.e. $f(x)=0\Rightarrow x = 0$ and that $f$ is surjective to generate $N$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Proposition :

Let $M$ be a nonzero module over ring $R$. A nonempty subset $B$ of $M$ is basis of $M$ if and only if every element of $M$ can be uniquely written as $R$-linear combination of elements of $B$.

Using above Proposition and the fact that $M$ is isomorphic to $N$ as $R$-modules, you can easily prove the desired result.